# Remove an entry from array in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have to remove a hash from array of hashes in elastic search. I have tried below queries, but none of them is working. Please help.

URL : POST https://127.0.0.1:9292/group/98902/_update

```
{
script : "for (int i = 0; i < ctx._source.users.size(); i++) 
{if(ctx._source.users[i].id == id){ctx._source.users.remove(i);}}",
"params" : {
    "id" : "9890"
}
}
```

OR

```
{script: "ctx._source.users.remove(user)",
"params" : {
    "user": 
        {
        id: "9890"
    }
}}
```

I am getting below response .

{
  "error": "ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[failed to execute script]; nested: ScriptException[dynamic scripting for [groovy] disabled]; ",
  "status": 400
}

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/21375

This is the soulution I found which must serve your purpose.

It worked for me, so give it a try

```
ctx._source.field.remove(ctx._source.field.indexOf(params.value))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since ES 1.5, "dynamic scripting" (executing a non sandboxed-script from a request) is disabled by default.

It's not recommanded, but you can opt-in with this configuration :

```
script.inline: true
script.indexed: true
```

See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html

Comment: Thanks Jeremie. Actually, I came to know, I dont have access to update the configuration. So, I have to get the document and update it.